# Kitchen sink clogged

Tags: vent, kitchen-sink, clog

Sink is clogged. Took out air admittance valve and it works fine. Added new one and it clogged again. Outside there's not clog. I don't know what else to do

Comment: Have you cleaned out the p-trap?  What size is your plumbing 1.5" or 2"?  Post a picture or you p-trap assembly.

Comment: What type of stopper does your sink have?

Comment: How much solids are going down the waste?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: There could also be a blockage in one or both of the hoses which run from the A.A.V. to the disposal or underside pipe (technically it's called tubing) and or from the AAV to a dishwasher.